# How to share github.io portfolio publicly?

Tags: github

I have managed to create a GitHub folder and uploaded my `.html` files. However, I do not see a publishing link in GitHub pages under settings.

Here is the screenshot of mine. As this website says, there is not even an option to make this repository public. The only available option is to upgrade and pay :(
[image]

How can I make this public?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the GitHub Free plan, GitHub pages are [available only for public repositories](https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/about-github-pages).

It looks like your repository is private. You could either make it public, or upgrade your plan to GitHub Pro or above.

To [make the repository public](https://help.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/setting-repository-visibility#making-a-repository-public), scroll down to the bottom of the settings page, and under "Danger Zone", select "Make public".